# AMD FX-4350 randomly switched from 4 to 2 cores

Tags: windows-10, multi-core

I am using standard build Windows 10 Professional and out of nowhere, I restarted my computer and task manager is only recognizing 2 of the 4 cores. I have checked my BIOS and it is recognizing all 4 cores. I have been using this CPU on Windows 10 for the last month and half and the CPU had all its cores and was working perfectly. I have searched the Internet without any luck. I now beg you geniuses for any answers.

Comment: Try going to msconfig > boot > advanced options> number of processors. What does that say?

Comment: @user193661 Thank you for your response. It is currently unchecked. I will check it and select 4 and see if it works.

Comment: @user193661 Unfortunately that did not work. Windows still only recognizes 2 cores.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/839391/task-manager-shows-one-processor-and-not-multiple-cores

Comment: Try the chipset drivers

Comment: @user193661 Thanks for the suggestion, but for some reason, the developer and advanced tabs are grayed out (http://i.imgur.com/oPGswoR.png). Also, my chipset drivers are currently up to date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29477/discussion-between-user193661-and-stephen-cioffi).

Comment: What exactly makes you think it only is recognizing 2 of your 4 cores?

Comment: @Ramhound Task Manager and Resource Monitor tells me. I have also noticed a huge performance difference in CPU as well (Which is why I decided to check task manager)