# Why device manager shows less CPU than task manager?

Tags: windows, cpu

OS: Windows 10

CPU: Intel xeon 8253

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/192465/intel-xeon-platinum-8253-processor-22m-cache-2-20-ghz.html

In task manager, it shows CPU cores as expected ( 16 cores, 32 threads, as spec ), but in the device manager - processor, it shows fewer CPUs, the number doesn't look like physical cores or threads.

Is that info(number) from BIOS?

Comment: Add screenshots to your post.

Comment: How many does device manager show? Without *some* information it is hard to know what is going on. Have you tried to count them?

Comment: 29 in device manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ACPI bugs in your motherboard's BIOS can cause this problem. Ensure that you are running the latest BIOS/firmware for your motherboard.
2. Make sure msconfig didn't limit the number of processors.

[Task Manager shows one processor (and not multiple cores)](https://superuser.com/questions/839391/task-manager-shows-one-processor-and-not-multiple-cores)

3. If you just replaced the CPU, windows may not detect it:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/930861/device-manager-does-not-show-updated-processor-information-on-a-window

Comment: for record and reference, it is a BIOS issue eventually.